# Unread Push messages (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have a Windows Phone application that can receive push messages. How can I know that user didn't open some push messages that he had recieved? (I mean that messages that user didn't open via TOAST)

**UPDATED**

Is there any other way to understand if user has recieved a push message and did't open it (did't clicl on TOAST)

Answer (score 1):

Push messages are fire and forget and thus cannot be enumerated as you describe.

The only thing I can recommend is to append a server ID to the NavigationUri of each message so the application can communicate back to the server to mark the message as read. Listing unread messages would fall on you, however, as they would need to come from your services.

However, there are several limitations to this approach:

1. The user may ignore the message
2. The application might be running (toast push messages aren't displayed)
3. The user may have poor connectivity

In the above cases, the ID would never be marked as read. You could still probably use this information to list messages from your server though.

*EDIT FOR UPDATED QUESTION*

No, there isn't